# Приоритетная очередь ошибка "Invalid heap"

Tags: c++, очередь

Имеется класс:

```
class TreeNode
{
    public:
    // Constructor.
    explicit TreeNode(const int& value);
    // Destructor.
    ~TreeNode();

    public:
    //! TreeNode smart pointer type.
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<TreeNode> TreeNodePtr;
    //! Color of node type.
    enum Color
    {
        WHITE,
        GRAY,
        BLACK
    };

    public:
    //! Node left pointer.
    TreeNodePtr leftPtr_;
    //! Parent node pointer;
    TreeNodePtr parentPtr_;
    //! Node right pointer.
    TreeNodePtr rightPtr_;
    //! Node value.
    int value_;
    //! Color of node.
    Color color_;
    //! Distance.
    int distance_;
    //! Started work with node.
    int discovered_;
    //! Stopped work with node.
    int finished_;
    //! Left arc weight.
    int leftArcWeight_;
    //! Right arc weight.
    int rightArcWeight_;
};
```

Имеется вектор nodes_ указателей TreeNode::TreeNodePtr:

```
    //! TreeNode::TreeNodePtr vector type.
typedef std::vector<TreeNode::TreeNodePtr> NodeVector;
    //! TreeNode::TreeNodePtr container.
NodeVector nodes_;
```

Эти указатели из вектора вставляются в приоритетную очередь:

```
    //! TreeNode::TreeNodePtr priority queue type.
typedef std::priority_queue<
    TreeNode::TreeNodePtr,
    std::vector<TreeNode::TreeNodePtr>,
    std::function<bool(TreeNode::TreeNodePtr, TreeNode::TreeNodePtr)> > NodeQueue;

NodeQueue queue(
    [](TreeNode::TreeNodePtr f, TreeNode::TreeNodePtr s) -> bool { return (f->distance_ > s->distance_); });

//! Sets arc weight.
for (size_t i = 0; i != nodes_.size(); ++i)
{
    //! Initializes priority queue.
    queue.push(nodePtr);
}
```

В цикле выбирается nodePtr с наименишим distance_.
При выполении условного опертора if программа падает с ошибкой "Invalid Heap" послe операции queue.pop();

```
while (!queue.empty())
{
    TreeNode::TreeNodePtr nodePtr = queue.top();

    //! Если выполняется это условие
    if (nodePtr->leftPtr_ &&
        nodePtr->leftPtr_->distance_ > (nodePtr->distance_ + nodePtr->leftArcWeight_))
    {
            nodePtr->leftPtr_->distance_ = nodePtr->distance_ + nodePtr->leftArcWeight_;
            nodePtr->leftPtr_->parentPtr_ = nodePtr;
    }

    //! Или выполняется это условие.
    if (nodePtr->rightPtr_ &&
        nodePtr->rightPtr_->distance_ > (nodePtr->distance_ + nodePtr->rightArcWeight_))
    {
            nodePtr->rightPtr_->distance_ = nodePtr->distance_ + nodePtr->rightArcWeight_;
            nodePtr->rightPtr_->parentPtr_ = nodePtr;
    }

    queue.pop(); //! Invalid heap.
}
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В процессе выполнения цикла `while (!queue.empty())` вы изменяете параметр `distance_`, который используется в функции сравнения элементов в приориретной очереди. Эта функция должна выполнять условия предиката [Strict Weak Ordering](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html). Но поскольку вы изменяете значения `distance_`, то инварианты становятся некорректными и появляется исключение `Invalid Heap`.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения. Как мне быть в этом случае?